# Zend Framework 1, Bvb Grid, resultset is filtered only for the current page

Tags: php, arrays, zend-framework

I have reached very strange problem using Zend Framework 1 and binding the resultset to BvbGrid.

We have a method which queries an external API. You need to specify the following params: *methodName*, *params*.

So the controller recieves a resultset as an array from the external API.

The resultset (in the database) is 4 columns - 1 string, 2 DateTime, 3 int, 4 int. And is with about 3000 rows.

When I recieve the resultset in the controller I bind it to Bvb Grid, which should evaluate in the view as columns with search boxes.

**So far, so good, when I search in the first or in the last column (string, int), it searches in the whole resultset.**

**But when I search 2, 3 (DateTime, int) it searches only in the current page.**

I don't understand why is that. There is no difference in data binding, or something.

The code is as follows

```
public function indexAction() {

    $pagesize = $this->_request->getPost('rows');
    $pagenum = $this->_request->getPost('page');

    $pagesize = ($pagesize) ? $pagesize : 30;
    $pagenum = ($pagenum) ? $pagenum : 1;

    $params = array();
    $params['page_num'] = $pagenum;
    $params['page_limit'] = $pagesize;

    if ($this->_request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        // additional search filter
        if ($this->_request->getPost('username')) {
            $params['username'] = $this->_request->getPost('username');
        }
        if ($this->_request->getPost('lastlogin')) {
            $params['lastlogin'] = $this->_request->getPost('lastlogin');
        }
        if ($this->_request->getPost('type')) {
            $params['type'] = $this->_request->getPost('type');
        }
        if ($this->_request->getPost('level')) {
            $params['level'] = $this->_request->getPost('level');
        }
    }
    if (($order_by = $this->_request->getPost('sidx')) && ($order_type = $this->_request->getPost('sord'))) {
        $params['order_by'] = $order_by;
        $params['order_by_type'] = $order_type;
    }


    $resultset = $this->web_service->_apiRequest('SearchUsers', $params);


    /**
     * The resultset is like
     * array(
        'found_rows' => 3000,
        'body'       => array(
                            'username'  => 'blabla',
                            'lastlogin' => '2014-02-25 13:33:38.1234',
                            'type'      => 1,
                            'level'     => 199
                        )
      );
     */
    $this->view->count = $resultset['found_rows'];

    if ($resultset['found_rows'] > 0 || $this->_request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        $grid = new Bvb_Grid_Deploy_JqGrid($this->_gridconfig);
        $grid->setSource(new Bvb_Grid_Source_Array($resultset['body']));
        $grid->getSource()->setTotalRecords($resultset['found_rows']);
        $grid->updateColumn('username', array('width' => '110',));
        $grid->updateColumn('lastlogin', array('width' => '110',));
        $grid->updateColumn('type', array('width' => '110',));
        $grid->updateColumn('level', array('width' => '110',));
        $grid->setJqgParams(array('caption' => 'resultset'
            , 'forceFit' => true
            , 'viewrecords' => true
            , 'rowList' => array(15, 30, 50)
            , 'altRows' => false
                )
        );

        $grid->ajax(get_class($grid));
        $grid->setNumberRecordsPerPage(30);
        $grid->setExport(array());
        $this->view->grid = $grid->deploy();
}
```

I have tried to examine the BvbGrid's code, but found nothing strange.

In another project the same code is used, and it works fine, without any problems on searching in any column. I have dump'd the API response to be sure it gives me 3000 records, and it actually is and they are in the way as in the comment. I really cannot find the reason why i.e. the lastlogin column searches only on the current page.

If someone can help me, or give me directions where to look at to fix the issue (maybe somewhere in the BvbGrid's code?) I will appreciate it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does the sorting work correctly on basic `Bvb_Grid_Deploy_Table` with the array?

Comment: Yep, it sorts the already recieved array